# Host Fragments inside an Activity class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can you host a fragment inside a class that extends Activity or do you have to extend FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two implementations of the fragment system.

One is native to API Level 11. To use those fragments, you can inherit from `Activity`, but then your app will only run on Android 3.0 and higher.

One is from the Android Support package. It works going all the way back to API Level 4. For that, you inherit from `FragmentActivity` and use the backport's version of the `Fragment` classes (mostly in `android.support.v4.app` instead of `android.app`. You can read more about the Android Support package in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am working with API Level 11 and above. I have a Google map v2 Fragment that works when I host it in a class that extends Activity. However, I have another piece of UI fragment(just a textView and a button) that seems to only work then I extend FragmentActivity on the host. I'd like to combine the two.

Comment: @user1923613: Perhaps you should ask a StackOverflow question, where you supply the code for "another piece of UI fragment" and explain why you think "that seems to only work then I extend FragmentActivity".

Comment: Yep. Maybe I should get some sleep. Anyway, here's what my question should have been [Why does this only work inside a host class that extends FragmentActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167554/why-does-this-only-work-inside-a-host-class-that-extends-fragmentactivity)