# How can I use Listview in a fragment that works on 2.2?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

Is there anyway to use listview in a fragment? I am using ViewPager to swipe amongst my fragments (following this: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) and it works pretty good, but I'd like a listview in each fragments. The problem is that I should use `ListFragment`, but I want my app to be able to run on a device with Android 2.2 and `ListFragments` work only from 3.0. Later I will customize this listview so how could I use a Listview in a fragment that actually works on 2.2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that I should use ListFragment, but I want my app to be able to run on a device with Android 2.2 and ListFragments work only from 3.0.

Incorrect.

As [I wrote yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167288/host-fragments-inside-an-activity-class/14167333#14167333), there are two implementations of the fragment system.

One is native to API Level 11. The `ListFragment` implementation for this is `android.app.ListFragment`, and you use it with a regular `Activity`.

One is from the Android Support package. It works going all the way back to API Level 4. For that, you inherit from `FragmentActivity` and use the backport's version of the `Fragment` classes (mostly in `android.support.v4.app` instead of `android.app`. In the case of `ListFragment`, you would use
`android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`. You can read more about the Android Support package in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I imported the right .Fragment and works like charm!

Comment: Anyway, can listfragment be customized as a listview? so having a picture, a radio button etc in one list item?

Comment: @JaniBela: You set up your rows in a `ListFragment` the same way you do with a `ListView`, by way of your adapter.